# Deserialize json object from a combobox data (loaded from database) Winform

Tags: c#, json, winforms, combobox

Good morning, I'm having a hard time finding solution to my problem. I have a combobox which is populated using datasource which is from DB and those data where JSON objects. How will I deserialize those data?
This is the JSON data from Database:

`{"displayname":{"value":"Test","scope":"contacts","verified":"0"},"address":{"value":"","scope":"private","verified":"0"},"website":{"value":"","scope":"private","verified":"0"},"email":{"value":"","scope":"contacts","verified":"0"},"avatar":{"scope":"contacts","verified":"0"},"phone":{"value":"01234567890","scope":"private","verified":"0"},"twitter":{"value":"","scope":"private","verified":"0"}}`

And below is what will be shown in the combobox. I don't want a JSON object in my combobox but instead a deserialized data. Ex: I want to only show the names in my combobox which is the value under displayname in JSON Object.

[image]

Comment: You should create a class which represent the json structure. Get all the json strings in to one string collection. Deserialize the string and create a class object for each of them and create a collection of class objects and bind that collection to the ComboBox by setting DisplayMember property of ComboBox

Comment: You can deserialize data into `JObject` and map to the object for ComboBox or create corresponding types/classes and deserialize given data to these types.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install `Newtonsoft.Json` package from NuGet. then you can Deserialize your JSON string and add it to your Combobox items.

e.g

```cs
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
//using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    string jsonStr = "Your JsonString ... ";
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonStr);
    string[] lst = parsed.Properties().Select(q => q.Name).ToArray();
    comboBox1.Items.AddRange(lst);
```

---

if you want to have separate `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` you can use your `JProperty` array as a DataSource.

e.g

```cs
    string jsonStr = "Your JsonString ... ";
    var parsed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonStr);
    comboBox1.DataSource = parsed.Properties().ToArray();
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
```

when you use a DataSource the `comboBox1.SelectedItem` also is a JProperty. so you can use this object to access other data in your json string.

e.g

```cs
   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // selectedValue is equal to `value` in the json string
      var selectedValue = ((JProperty)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value.Value<string>("value");
      MessageBox.Show(selectedValue); 
   }
```

Comment: Thank you @AliReza. Gonna try this and will update you later,.

Comment: I'll give a +1 for this one since it is useful but not actually solve my problem or maybe I just don't know the additional codes needed to get the needed data. Thank you

Comment: thanks. what do you need exactly?  I just used `your sample JSON `string in these examples. maybe your data structure is different. 
you can tweak this answer to get your desired results ...  or ask if you have any questions. @James

Comment: I already found the solution using this one. RootObject test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstr); with this classes  public class Displayname
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Displayname displayname { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Create a class as your Combo box Data Source like this,

```
public class Displayname
{
    public string scope;
    public string value; // as your display member in combobox
    public int verified;
}
public class MyData
{
    public string address;
    public Displayname displayname;
}
```

then deserialize your JSON to an object of MyData like this

```
string json = @"{
                'displayname': {'value' : 'james@example.com',
  'scope': 'contacts'},
  'verified': '0' } ,  'address':'blabla' ";
    var t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
combobox.datasource = t.displayname; // not sure about syntax of this line,
```

Then in combobox property set the display member as value (this is the name of the property you have in your json and also you have in Deserialized class which is Displayname). exactly write the the name of the property that you want.

by the way, value is not good name for display member and the json string you provided I believe is not right json. good luck